# why i didnot get output for below code need explanation?

Tags: java

```
public class Triangle 
{

    float length;  //declared length as float
    float breadth;  //declared breadth as float
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Triangle Triangle1 = new Triangle();
        Triangle Triangle2 = new Triangle();

        float area; //declared area as float

        Triangle1.length = 11;
        Triangle1.breadth = 22;
        Triangle2.breadth = 15;
        Triangle2.length = 20;

        area = 0.5 * Triangle1.length * Triangle1.breadth;
        System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

        area = 0.5 * Triangle2.length * Triangle2.breadth;
        System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

    }
}
```

i have declared the area as float earlier and i got complie time error for that, when i changed it into double, i can able to get the below output.
need to know why...??

float area;

```
Error:(24, 49) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
Error:(27, 49) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
```

Comment: The error is telling you why in plain English.

Comment: A `double` is 64-bits, a `float` is 32-bits. You are multiplying two 64-bit numbers and trying to store the result in 32-bits.

Comment: in 15sec 3 different correct answers ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several mistakes.

- Please keep the naming conventions. Class starts with the capitalized letter, variable don't. So.. `Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle()`.
- In order to keep all the data in `float`, you need to multiply all the numbers in `float` as well. 0,5 is `double` as default, having the bigger decimal precision than `float`. There are two ways to fix that:

Use `F` or `f` indicator (I recommend the capitalized one) to say that you work with `float`. Otherwise Java unserstands it as `double`:

```
area = 0.5F * triangle1.length * triangle1.breadth;
```

Or cast all the resutl to `float`:

```
area = (float) 0.5 * triangle1.length * triangle1.breadth;
```

Comment: i didn't get the first comment

Comment: I didn't get your reply. What do you not understand?

Comment: as you mentioned class starts with capitlal letters and object created in small letters

Comment: Just use class names with capital letter and variables with the small one. Like: `Triangle triangle1 = new ...` instead of `Triangle Triangle1 = new ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java by default number like 2.553 are **double** so when you do

`area = 0.5 * Triangle1.length * Triangle1.breadth;`

you are doing **double * float * float**. If you want to use 0.5 as float you need to add letter **f** after number so your code will looks like:

```
area = 0.5f * Triangle1.length * Triangle1.breadth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Add `f` after every initialisation of float variables, like `Triangle1.length = 11f;`

Thus the code becomes:

```
public class Triangle {

float length; // declared length as float
float breadth; // declared breadth as float

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Triangle Triangle1 = new Triangle();
    Triangle Triangle2 = new Triangle();

    float area; // declared area as float

    Triangle1.length = 11f;
    Triangle1.breadth = 22f;
    Triangle2.breadth = 15f;
    Triangle2.length = 20f;

    area = 0.5f * Triangle1.length * Triangle1.breadth;
    System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

    area = 0.5f * Triangle2.length * Triangle2.breadth;
    System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

}
```

}

2. Make the `area` variable `double` type:

Your code thus becomes:

```
public class Triangle {

float length; // declared length as float
float breadth; // declared breadth as float

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Triangle Triangle1 = new Triangle();
    Triangle Triangle2 = new Triangle();

    double area; // declared area as float

    Triangle1.length = 11;
    Triangle1.breadth = 22;
    Triangle2.breadth = 15;
    Triangle2.length = 20;

    area = 0.5 * Triangle1.length * Triangle1.breadth;
    System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

    area = 0.5 * Triangle2.length * Triangle2.breadth;
    System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

}
```

}

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Do this.

```
    public class Triangle 
{
    float length;  //declared length as float
    float breadth;  //declared breadth as float

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Triangle Triangle1 = new Triangle();
        Triangle Triangle2 = new Triangle();

        float area; //declared area as float

        Triangle1.length = 11;
        Triangle1.breadth = 22;
        Triangle2.breadth = 15;
        Triangle2.length = 20;

        area = (float)0.5 * Triangle1.length * Triangle1.breadth;
        System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);

        area = (float)0.5 * Triangle2.length * Triangle2.breadth;
        System.out.println("The area of Triangle is" + " " + area);
    }
}
```